# Are "be in tune with" and "understand" interchangeable in some situations?

Tags: word-usage

In my other post ([the grammar rule of "against my hearing you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240323/109190)) I said

> If it was "against/prevent I hearing you", I would **be in tune with** the meaning.

I am aware that "be in tune with" means "having a good understanding" and I was trying to express

> If it was "against/prevent I hearing you", I would understand the meaning clearly.

and I used "*be in tune with*" to convey that meaning.

Do they mean the same?

In other words, are "*be in tune with*" and "understand" interchangeable in this kind of situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Be in tune with" has a somewhat different field of meaning than "understand."

> I understand you but disagree

is idiomatic whereas

> I am in tune with you but disagree

is not idiomatic.

> I agree with your conclusion even though I don't understand your argument

is idiomatic as is

> I am in tune with your conclusion even though I don't understand your argument.

In other words "in tune with" indicates agreement or sympathy without **necessarily** implying understanding. Of course, understanding is frequently associated with agreement or sympathy, and thus "in tune with" certainly does **not** imply a failure to understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in tune with someone/something you have a good understanding of someone or something, meaning that you know how someone behaves or how something works. This refers to the fact that you understand them as a whole. In other words, it doesn't refer to a particular instance.

sometimes **understand** and **be in tune with** are interchangeable:

> He is more in tune with his players today, because he has asked them for their opinions. ([cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-tune-with-someone-something))

in the example above if you use understand the sentence still makes sense, but this isn't always the case as @Jeff Morrow mentioned in his examples.